# Hiding library project implementation from client app

Tags: android

I'm building an android library project, which will act like an SDK. Other apps will include the project, and call methods from it as normal.

I'm providing the functionality to the client app by means of a singleton, i.e. `MySdk.getInstance().doSomethingGreat()`. However, I only want the desired SDK behaviour to be available. My library has has many classes organised into several packages, which naturally contain many public variables and methods. Currently the client app can access lots of stuff which I don't want it to. How can I hide all this stuff from the client app?

The only way I can think of is to organise all my classes into one package, so that I can keep all my methods and variables `private, protected, or default` visibility. But that's really poor organisation to work with, surely there is another way?

Comment: Actually I don't think there is, _package-private_ and _protected_ access modifiers are the way to do it.

Comment: "How can I hide all this stuff from the client app?" -- you don't, generally. You can try to rig up ProGuard to obfuscate the non-API stuff, though I have no idea how well that works with a library project.